# Python creates Folder inside docker image but remove when processing completes

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Python Program does create folder and put some files over there. But when i try to run the program inside docker via `CMD`
It creates the folder and put files over there and upon completion, the folder somehow gets removed or doesnt show inside the docker image.

I have tried the following things:

1. Check Folder Exist after creating - It shows folder created over there.
2. Check inside the docker image using bash - It doesnt show the folder and contents.

The dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Upgrade installed packages

RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

WORKDIR /code
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y install python3-venv
RUN apt -y install python3-setuptools libffi-dev python3-dev
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN apt install -y unzip

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential swig

WORKDIR /code
RUN python3 -m venv .env
RUN . .env/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN . .env/bin/activate && pip install pyenchant && pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0
RUN apt-get install -y libenchant1c2a

RUN mkdir embeddings
COPY . .
RUN curl -L http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip --output glove.zip
RUN unzip -o glove.zip -d embeddings/

RUN . .env/bin/activate && python nltk_install.py
CMD . .env/bin/activate && python main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to filesystem are not stored in docker image. They exist in container created from an image but if you use 'docker run' command a new container is created.

Comment: I have run the docker image by  `docker run 7cba10252ee5` but `docker container ls` shows no container. How can i fix that

Comment: try 'docker ps -a' and then if you find your container 'docker start <container id>'